# Simple search returning blank screen

Tags: simple-search

I'm having inconsistent behavior getting search results. The page in question is here:

http://utk.edu/alpha/

Using that search form with terms like "english" or "calendar", etc. Sometimes the results (or no-results) return just fine. Sometimes, however, the form sends you to www.utk.edu (as is the action on the form) and the process gets "killed" and shows only a white screen.

I cannot really explain why it works sometimes, and not others. I have very similar code (essentially just searching a different channel) elsewhere:
https://www.utk.edu/volunteer_stories/
And that page works fine.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

EDIT: I did a bit more experimentation. I duplicated the template and put it in a different place:
https://www.utk.edu/aboutut/alpha

At that location, the search seems to work a bit more. However, it's the same exact template.

Comment: Tried a dozen different search terms - some of which would certainly deliver results others that certainly would not.  Got a white screen every time.  Might be worth specifying a 'no_result' page in your search form tag - this would help you work out if you are simply getting no results, or there is a problem during tag execution.  https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/search/advanced.html#no_result_page

Comment: I do have a no-results page. The tag I am using  is: {exp:search:simple_form  result_page="search" no_result_page="search/no-result" search_in="entries" channel="a_z_index"}

Comment: Search working fine in my limited testing.  Seems to be trying to load a logo in the wrong path tho: https://www.utk.edu/alpha/assets/css/png/header-logo.png